# SIFT features and classification of images?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification, svm, sift

I am new to image processing, and I want to extract image features in order to do some classification. I am having problems understanding the pipeline.

As far as I understand, I have a images and I run the SIFT algorithm on them. This gives me a set of descriptors for each images, the number varies, with fixed length of 128.

I then proceed to cluster them, since it is not possible to apply algorithms on varying number of features. For this, I stack up all the descriptors of all images and I run the k means algorithm with the desired number of clusters. What I get are k number of features of length 128.

Here is where I am confused, so I now have these new descriptors right, what do I do with them? I don't understand how I can plug them into a classifier if they represent all images? Should each images have their own separate features to be fed into a classifier?

I am sure I did not understand the concept, but can anybody please clarify what happens after I get a k*128 sized matrix? What is fed into for example an SVM classifier and how? How does this k means result suffice to train a classifier?

Thanks!

EDIT: I might have confused keypoints and descriptors, sorry new to image processing!

Answer (score 3):

You should look into the image classification/image retrieval approach known as 'bag of visual words' - it is extremely relevant. A bag of visual words is a fixed-length feature vector **v** which summarises the occurrences of the features in an image. This makes use of what is called a *codebook* (also called a *dictionary* from historical uses in text retrieval), which in your case is built from your K-means clustering. To make **v** for a given image, the simplest approach is to assign **v**[j] the proportion of SIFT descriptors that are closest to the jth cluster centroid. This means the length of **V** is K, so it is independent of the number of SIFT features that are detected in the image.

Concretely, suppose you've done K means clustering with K = 100. Let's use **c**i to denote the *ith* cluster centre. For SIFT, this would be a vector of size 128. Now, for a given input image, you make this vector **v**, which is of size 100 and initialized with zeros. You then extract features from the image, and their corresponding descriptors. Let's say there are N descriptors, and we will call them **d**0, **d**2,...,**d**(N-1), where **d**j is the *jth* descriptor. For each **d**j you compute the vector distance between it and the cluster centres **c**0, **c**2,...**c**99. You then take the cluster index **k** with the lowest distance to **d**j, and increment: **v**[k]+=1. Note that this process can be parallelised very well particularly on GPUs. Also it can be faster to replace this process using what is known as Approximate Nearest Neighbours, using e.g. the [FLANN](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/) library.

Comment: Thank you, just a question you say assign the proportion of sift descriptor that are closest to the jth cluster, could you perhaps give a simple example in your answer? I understand it theoretically, but I don't really understand how this new v is formed. From my understanding, v is a vector of the number of descriptors in each cluster for each image?